# Dapper .net, Bulk insert, how to pass current date for datetime column

Tags: dapper, bulkinsert

I am doing bulk insert into a SQL table using Dapper plus. Here is the code

```
 DapperPlusManager.Entity<HardwareComponentType>("WithInsertIfNotExists").Table("dbo.Components")
                                     .UseBulkOptions(options => {
                                         options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                                     }).Identity(x=>x.ComponentId).Map("Name", "Name").Map("Status", "Status").MapValue("getDate()", "ModifiedDateTime");
```

As you can see, for the column, "modifiedDateTime, I am trying to pass "getDate", but I am unable to do so. I am getting exception. Basically, it is taking that as a string.
How do I pass getDate() as parameter in this syntax, that is my question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` method can take any value, such as:

```cs
.Map(x => DateTime.Now, "ModifiedDateTime")
```

That is important to use the `x =>` part, as it means the `DateTime.Now` will be evaluated for every entity and every time this method is called.

The `MapValue` method should only be used if the `ModifiedDateTime` is a constant. For example, if you are creating a custom `DapperContext` only for this `BulkInsert`, so all entities will have the same value. But in your case, you look using the `GlobalContextMapping`, so the `Map(x =>` method is the one you are looking for.